# How to design search algorithm to find set of items that are most relevant to the query?

Tags: algorithm, search

A store has `3 products` in its catalogue. Each product has assigned probability of belonging to 4 classes: `colour_yellow`, `colour_red`, `gender_male`, `gender_female`.

```
product_1 = colour_yellow(p=0.7),colour_red(p=0.4),gender_male(p=0),gender_female(p=1)

product_2 = colour_yellow(p=0.3),colour_red(p=0.8),gender_male(p=1),gender_female(p=0)

product_3 = colour_yellow(p=0.1),colour_red(p=0.4),gender_male(p=1),gender_female(p=1)
```

Mary has access to an electronic catalogue where she is asked how does she feel about these 4 classes, so that store bot can recommend her best products. She answered, I like `colour_yellow` a lot, and `colour_red`a little, and I also seek `gender_female` products only.

How to calculate each products recommendation score to Mary's preferences ?:

I am thinking to solve it by by computing one value for each `product` by multiplying probability values for same category across products by 100, 1000, 10000 etc (to accommodate for positional values) and then sum it, so that the final value could be compared with query value. Example:

Product scores:

```
val product_1 = (0.7 * 100) + (0.4 * 1000) +  (0 * 10000) + (1 * 100000)
val product_2 = (0.3 * 100) + (0.8 * 1000) +  (1 * 10000) + (0 * 100000)
val product_3 = (0.1 * 100) + (0.4 * 1000) +  (1 * 10000) + (0 * 100000)
```

and Mary's `query score`

```
val q = ((1 * 100) + weight 7) + ((1 * 1000) + weigh 3) +  (0 * 10000) + (1 * 100000)
```

with results as:

```
product_1: 10,470
product_2: 1,830
product_3: 11,410
query: 11,100 (without weights)
```

Give these results store could infer to recommend  `product_3` and `product_1` with confidence of perfect match for `product_3` as query - `product_3`: 11,100 - 11,410

Am I on a right track ?

Comment: I'm having difficulty following your question. Shouldn't c1,c2,c3 for i1 add up to 1? Otherwise you either don't have probabilities or a thing can belong to multiple classes.

Comment: I think you are more or less just calculating an arbitrary number which doesn't make much sense. Working with relative errors seems to be difficult too, because your probabilities can be 0 and 1 leading to an infinite error i.e. division by 0. The simplest thing seems to be to take the difference. With q you would get differences for i1 to i3 of 1, 0.4 and 0.6, so i2 would be the best.

Comment: Please revise the question, is far too confused, and it's not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: revised the Q, apologies. yes ideal product will have relationship with multiple classes. @maraca elastic search has solved similar problem using inverted index, would that be the solution?

Comment: is there any clever math or algorithm that tackled this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by using [cosine-similarity-algorithm](http://stefansavev.com/blog/cosine-similarity/)